# React Native Web - Module not found: Can't resolve '../../App'

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-web

My Expo React Native app works on Expo iOS.

However, when I press W in the Ubuntu terminal and am taken to my web browser, the webpage displays the following:

```
/home/pixel/Documents/Name/Project/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../App' in '/home/pixel/Documents/Name/Project/node_modules/expo'
```

I use a custom path for `App.js` but it does work on Expo iOS.

I've tried `npx react-native link`.

Comment: I'd like to put in the title "App.js not found" but SO blocks me from doing this. I'm not sure why!

Comment: I tried to find a title that was allowed through the filter. Hope that's close enough to what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickRoberts, that's a good title